# Using Pi 2 as feedthrough of mouse/keyboard to computer

Tags: keyboard, peripherals, mouse

The goal is to connect a mouse to my raspberry Pi, and have it connected to a computer (both linux and windows will be used). I want to have a LED light up whenever I use a right mouse click. So the input would be mouse -> raspberry -> computer. Where I want the raspberry to have a led light up on certain actions.

Ideally I'd be able to configure this for not only certain mouse actions, but also keyboard.

Thing is, I have no idea where to start. Or if it is even remotely possible at all. Most challenging thing I can imagine is connecting the pi as a input peripheral. So any advice is greatly appriciated.

EDIT:
Ideally the Pi would be connected as an actual USB device with a USB cable. This is to best imitate a mouse/keyboard and it's latencies.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Why spend $35 to emulate a $5 mouse?

Comment: Goal is to have a visual LED indicator for certain actions. With this and a high speed camera I want to do some testing on latencies. So I want to measure the time between the LED lighting up, and an action happening on screen. Also why use an overly expencive pi 2? becouse I have one laying around, and as a microprocessor board with output pins it seemed like it could do the job.

Comment: It would also  be a great surveillance device like the FBI used on that mobster when they couldn't crack his PGP.

Answer (score 1):

Following the approach given in the question *mouse -> raspberry -> computer*, one solution could be to emulate an HID (*Human Interface Device*) with the Pi when connecting to the computer. So the Pi picks up all input coming from the mouse/keyboard, gets the info it needs (the certain action you intend to act upon), and relays all the input to the other computer faking to be a HID using it's GPIO ports.

See here (to not repeat what's written there):

- [Wake up Windows PC via USB event from a Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33405/wake-up-windows-pc-via-usb-event-from-a-raspberry-pi)
- [Can the Pi Emulate an HID device with via USB?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32197/can-the-pi-emulate-an-hid-device-with-via-usb)
- [Can I use Raspberry Pi as a USB peripheral device?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/271/can-i-use-raspberry-pi-as-a-usb-peripheral-device)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly because the Pi's USB port was occupied.

However you can use Arduino Leonardo with some SPI-to-USB-Host chip here.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what you need [USB over IP](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/). Your RPi will run Linux and do the thing =)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @SteveRobillard a **link** is provided. I know and I've been reading the fine manual, but this question is literally has a one-line answer. Why don;t you take a look at the official website of the project I've recommended?

Comment: This looks indeed very promising, and like a good solution. I am slightly worried about network latency though. Initially my idea was to use the RPi as an actual USB, so with a cable, to best imitate an actual mouse. although I notice I did not explicitly mention this in my question, for which my apologies. I edited my question to include this.
I will go with this if no USB sollution arises though.

Comment: The issue is that without including the pertinent details here your answer is only good as long as that link is functional.

Comment: @SteveRobillard the issue is, that if a whole project I'm referring to will go down with their website, then an answer will be useless, indeed. But it's not a reason to include the whole source code, right?

Comment: @Downquark no problem! take a look at [theese modules](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41) - it will make your USB-plugged RPi have an ethernet-via-usb =) And the setup scheme will be the same, but the latency will be different.

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin Correct me if I'm wrong, but does the guide apply to only Raspberry Pi Zero (and model A and A+)? The story being that the Pi 2 does not support USB OTG? After all if it did you could somehow use it as slave, so like a mouse as I intend in the first place?

Comment: @Downquark it is for a models yo've specified. If you need a USB OTG/slavemode for other versions - then you'll need a bridge on a separate chip. My good advice to you : make it work via network, then adjust your hardware profile if needed.